# What may I be missing while trying to install npm bootstrap to my project?

Tags: node.js, npm, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use npm to install bootstrap on my project. I have already

> `npm init` and confirmed package.json is on the associated folder.
> However, `npm install bootstrap` keeps bringing a dependency error
> npm ERR! code ENOSELF
> npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "bootstrap" under a package
> npm ERR! also called "bootstrap". Did you name your project the same
> npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! For more information, see:
> npm ERR!     https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-07-30T11_18_57_954Z-debug.log

How do I fix this error pls?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably named your package as a `bootstrap`, which prevents `npm` from installing the package with the **same** name from the registry.
Try to rename your package to `bootstrap-test` in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "bootstrap-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "My first bootstrap project!"
}
```